# Configure multicast group address on CentOs, and set multi devices to join this group address

Tags: centos, multicast

all, i have 3 computers hosted on the same LAN with CentOs 6.5 OS installed, and i want to configure a specific Multicast Group IP address for own purpose, rather than the default 224.0.0.1; then add the all computers NIC to the group address. Anyone could tell me how to configure it?  the hosts basic configuration is as below:

```
# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4B:B6:29  
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4b:b629/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

# cat config-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64|grep MULTICAST
CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y
```

Thanks in advance and looking forward your help.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this additional multicast address?

Comment: interesting in how to change the default all-host-group-address in the LAN, Thanks

Comment: ok, but why? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?